# Is 2 GB of RAM enough to handle common programming IDE's?

Tags: memory, eclipse, netbeans, ide

I'm going to buy a laptop with 2GB of RAM and a 500 GB Hard Drive for college use (not heavy programming, but will be using two IDE's: NetBeans and Eclipse).

I've checked that NetBeans uses mostly 500 MB of RAM and assuming I'll be having a browser with many tabs running, lets say another 500 MB of Ram is going to be used. And lets say that the system itself will use another 500 MB.

It feels like people say you need more than 4 GB of RAM, while it seems like you can do light programming with only 2 GB? Is this enough?

Comment: First, you should leave 2GB just for a standard windows OS, and 4 if you plan to run medium to heavy productivity software like MS Outlook. Additionally Development activities are often quite significant, and both NetBeans and Eclipse are ram-intensive tools. They are saying this based on their experience (I as a .net developer say 8GB minimum, 16 preferred, if it is your main work desktop). You would be wise to heed their advice. A 2GB RAM chip to add to your laptop would be reasonably cheap, and well worth the investment. developers should not be minimalists when it comes to their PC.

Comment: I have 16GB of RAM and find myself using [6GB](https://i.imgur.com/MamAygZ.png) constantly, [just from](https://i.imgur.com/R8kyFvw.png) Windows itself whilst having Chrome / Visual Studio / Notepad++ open.

Comment: Memory is super cheap, no reason not to get more.

Comment: For anybody who isn't versed into computers and who just asks me for a recommendable laptop for common applications like office, browser etc. I just say that it has to be at least 4GB RAM. The next bottleneck mostly becomes the Hard drive. However the CPU is mostly good enough but I cannot understand that there are still 2GB RAM laptops out there.

Comment: Perhaps the thing missing here is, that when dealing with IDEs, theres no such thing as "light programming". IDEs are large toolboxes, and there usually isn't a way to make it load only a small part of the kit. It doesn't matter if you are working with a 100-line script or a 10MB binary, except at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

My opinion: **NO.** 2GB of RAM *won't* be enough.

Since you also mention you could have a lot of browser tabs open, you'll experience a lot of frustration. Java programming environments also take up a substantial amount of memory.

I suggest you upgrade to at least 4GB RAM. Personally, I consider 8GB a minimum.